# Bind Button visibility to a method: C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, xamarin

I need to trigger a method if Button is visible. How do I bind the method( ex: OnButtonVisble) in xaml to the button ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of call

```
view.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

and

```
view.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
```

create a method for example SetButtonVisibility(ViewStates state) and inside set your button visibility AND do what you want to do in your "OnButtonVisble"

```
public void SetButtonVisibility(ViewStates state) {
    button.Visibility = state;
    if (state == ViewStates.Visible) {
        'ADD your OnButtonVisible code here
    }
}
```

You can add Action/Func as parameter if you want to use callback and add "OnButtonVisible" code as a delegate

Comment: I am setting the button visibility in some function. So I just want to trigger another function when ever button's visibility is set to "true".

Comment: Can I add handler like button.PropertyChanged handler ?